# Mailgun in Laravel not working?

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

I am looking around for some answers to my problem. I really do not know what in my settings or code is wrong but i can't make the sending of email work.

Here is my `mail.php` values

```
'driver' => 'mailgun',
'host' =>  'smtp.mailgun.org',
'port' => 587,
'from' => array('address' => 'here is my email', 'name' => 'Some name here'),
'encryption' => 'tls',
'username' => null,
'password' => null,
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

Here is  the `services.php`

```
'mailgun' => array(
'domain' =>'my domain here' ,
'secret' => 'my secret key here',
),
```

Here is my code for Sending.

```
$data = array(
                'msg'   =>  'You have successfully registered ',
                'url'   =>  'someURL'
            );          
try{
    Mail::send('emails.REGISTRATION_SUCCESS', $data, function($message){
    $message->from('admin@something.com', 'y System');
    $message->to('myemail@gmail.com')->subject(' Registration Successful!');
    });
   }catch(Exemption $e){echo $e->getMessage();} 
   echo 'hello';
```

**I am having this error whenever I run the code.**

> Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found

I really do not know where in this code i am wrong. I am currently stuck right now. it still not sending any email. I really dont know now. please hep me. I am looking at some tutorials and almost same question post but nothing is working. any suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: yes apparently whenever i try to run the code I have the page

"Whoops, looks like something went wrong." 
But when I check my email, to see if  It send something...It do not send any test email to me.

Comment: Well, then check the laravel log for the stack trace. Also update the question with the error.

Comment: I meant the actual error... not the "Oops" message. In the laravel log you'll find the error stack trace.

Comment: I have this some kind of error.

Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found

Comment: Improved Code Edits and Enhanced  readability about the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Laravel mail documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail):

> #### Driver Prerequisites
>
> The API based drivers such as Mailgun and SparkPost are often simpler and faster than SMTP servers. If possible, you should use one of these drivers. **All of the API drivers require the Guzzle HTTP library, which may be installed via the Composer package manager:**
>
> `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this later today!

Comment: can i do the installation of this without composer? or not via composer?

Answer (score 0):

in you `composer.json` file add this `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"` in `require` portion then `composer update` for more info click [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#introduction)
 or just in your terminal on the laravel root folder run `composer require "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0"`

Answer (score 0):

Just do as @Martin suggested

```
$ composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

from command-line on your project path.

This will install the required packages. Also refer [guzzle github link](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)

Just in case, you are doing this directly on production (which is really very dangerous), you may follow @bashar's answer.